# Update a column to -1 when not match with source ,when matched then the actual value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Can you please help me with this.

i have a `source table`  and a `target table.`
I want to update a column in the target `table A` using the source `table B`.
If i find a match with `table B` using `inner join` then i want to update it in the `target table column`, else if there is not match i want to update the column in target table to -1.

ie.something like this...

```
update table a
set a.column1= b.column1
from table a inner join table b
on a.column1=b.column1
```

as you know the above query will only update `target table's` column only when a matching value is found in the source table.

but i also want the `target table 's` column to be set to `-1` when no match is found with source table b.

I have tried a lot and could get to the solution.
Can anyone try this out for me...Thanks in advance.

Comment: Change the join to a left join and have the value be isnull(b.column1, -1)

Comment: Have you looked at the [MERGE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) statement?  This would facilitate any other matches/non-matches in the future.  Otherwise, Sean's comment is perfect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this. I would think that a NULL would be more appropriate than a surrogate -1 value but that is up to you. Personally I really dislike a placeholder value when NULL is what actually makes sense.

```
update table a 
set a.column1 = isnull(b.column1, -1)
from table a 
left join table b on a.column1=b.column1
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response Sean, you have saved my day.